# How do I efficiently close a large number of clips as soon as they have finished playing?

Tags: java

I have a game where sound effects are played using this method:

```
 AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
          TheGame.class.getResource(url));
          Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();


           clip.open(inputStream);
           clip.start();
```

However, not closing the clips obviously builds up memory, and the fixes I've tried cause the game to freeze up occasionally.
I tried :

1. creating a new LineListener for every single clip that closes the clip when it stops. freezes up game OFTEN.
2. Having one LineListener that listens to every clip that closes them when they stop. freezes often as well.
3. Same as #2, but dividing the clips among multiple LineListeners, I've tried 4, 6, and 10, and all freeze up the game at least once.
4. Never closing the clips, eventually the game will stop playing sounds and freeze up
5. setting the clips to null as soon as they're opened, same result as #4

I'm not sure why closing clips seems to take so much time that it freezes up the entire game, is there a more time-efficient way?

Here is the code for the LineListener's update method I'm using:

```
    @Override
public void update(LineEvent event) {
     if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP){
               Clip c = (Clip) event.getSource();
               c.close();
               c.removeLineListener(this);
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you really load that many unique sounds? `Clip` is designed to be started/rewound/stopped and thus can be reused repeatedly. Not really a Java programmer here, but I think you should be caching the `Clip` objects, not closing them each time.

Comment: So you're saying each sound effect should have its own clip and be open from the beginning, and I call start on each clip when I want it to play? Or is there a better object to use for my purpose? Because I don't have that many sounds, but I do have a lot of instances where a sound is rapidly played tens of times in a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment above, you should reuse the existing `Clip` object.

```
Map<String, Clip> clips = new HashMap<String, Clip>();

public synchronized void play(String url) {
    Clip clip = clips.get(url);
    if(clip == null) {
        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
            TheGame.class.getResource(url));
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(inputStream);
        clips.put(url, clip);
    }
    if(clip.isRunning())
        clip.stop();
    clip.setFramePosition(0);
    clip.start(); 
}
```

You will need to get a bit more creative if you need to overlap the same sound with itself. Note that I have placed this in a `synchronized` method to protect the `Map` from concurrent modification if you should happen to be calling this from multiple threads.

Comment: So this solution seems to work, but when rapidly playing sound effects it skips over quite a few sounds, and it seems to be happening when the sounds are being played at almost the exact same time, but not by different threads. With some debugging it shows that the clip.start() is indeed reached every time the method is called, any idea how this could be fixed?

Comment: So my current solution is to make a decorator that turns each clip into a sort of linked list, and if a clip is already running when i want to play that same sound effect, I create a new clip and link it to that one, and so on. The magic number of clips that needed to be linked together ended up being 5, and that only happens in one or two instances. Is this a good solution>?

Comment: I assumed you'd probably need to load some clips multiple times if you were trying to overlap them too much. I think how many will depend on how long the clip is and how frequently you try to play it. I'm not familiar with decorators, but if I needed multiple clips, I would probably have made the map's value type a `List<Clip>`.